# Solution of partiell differential equation using the fundamental solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

So I have a partial differential equation:

$$P(D)u =  \sum_{a \leq m}^{}  c_{a}  u^{a} = f$$

When I have the fundamental solution

$$P(D)T =    \delta _{0} $$

I can solve the equation with (Malgrange-Ehrenpreis, Hörmander)

$$u  =f\ast  T\;\;\; for\;\;\; f  \in   C_{c} ^{\infty} $$

but what should I do if I have a partial differential equation with

$$ f =   \chi _{ [0,1] } ? $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same thing. Observe that
$$
\chi_{[0,1]}\ast\phi\in C_c^\infty\quad\forall\phi\in C_c^\infty.
$$
Then you can define $T\ast\chi_{[0,1]}$ by
$$
\langle T\ast\chi_{[0,1]},\phi\rangle=\langle T,\phi\ast\chi_{[0,1]}\rangle\quad\forall\phi\in C_c^\infty.
$$